# How to show the actual username instead of nobody in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, command-line-interface, putty

I'm trying to find the memory usage for each account on my VPS. I use the "top" command to achieve that but the problem is that it is not showing the actual username for each account. I have four accounts at this time and they are all shown as "nobody" username. How can I get the actual username?

Comment: nobody in linux is system user "grep nobody /etc/passwd"

Answer (score 1):

Create service accounts with names you like, adjust the software you are running to start with those service accounts you created.

As @c4f4t0r mentioned nobody is an actual account.  And it is often used as the default un-privileged account.

Ideally you shouldn't really have anything running as nobody and each service will be running as a unique account instead of this generic account.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Can you tell me how to check memory/ram usage for each cPanel account on VPS running CentOS 6.5 ?. For example, if I have two accounts with usernames "tresby" and "reftol" and I want to identify which is using high resources in order to ban. How can I check then for each % usage of memory? Thank you.

Comment: I do not know anything about cpanel crap.  If you want useful information, SSH into the box and use top/ps.